# Behat test "Then I should see Laravel 5" fails in laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, bdd, behat

I have a Macbook with OS El Capitan. In my new Laravel application (created by 
`$ composer create-project laravel/laravel my_app`), I type:

```
$ php artisan serve
```

And in the browser (Safari or Chrome) on localhost:8000 I successfully see black text "Laravel 5" on the webpage.

I have a hometest.feature file in features/ that looks like:

```
Feature:
  In order to prove that Behat works as intended
  We want to test the home page for a phrase
  Scenario: Root Test
    When I am on the homepage
    Then I should see "Laravel 5"
```

I have a /features/bootstrap/FeaturesContext.php file which looks like:

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    /**
     * Initializes context.
     *
     * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
     * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
     * context constructor through behat.yml.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
}
```

I have a behat.yml file that looks like:

```
default:
    extensions:
        Laracasts\Behat:
            # env_path: .env.behat
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            default_session: laravel
            base_url: http://localhost:8000
            laravel: ~
```

When I run (localhost running or not running = doesn't differ result):

```
$ vendor/bin/behat
```

The console output is:

```
Feature:
  In order to prove that Behat works as intended
  We want to test the home page for a phrase

  Scenario: Root Test             # features/hometest.feature:5
    When I am on the homepage     # FeatureContext::iAmOnHomepage()
    Then I should see "Laravel 5" # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
      The text "Laravel 5" was not found anywhere in the text of the current page. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ResponseTextException)

--- Failed scenarios:

    features/hometest.feature:5

1 scenario (1 failed)
2 steps (1 passed, 1 failed)
0m0.12s (20.26Mb)
```

Why does my simple "I should see 'Laravel 5' test fail? If the localhost needs to be running, how do I run my test at the same time? When I start up the local host, nothing I type in the terminal receives a response anymore.

My directory structure of applicable folders:

```
app/
bootstrap/
...
features/
    bootstrap/
        FeatureContext.php
    hometest.feature
...
.env.behat
behat.yml
composer.json
...
etc.
```

Thank you!

Comment: why don't you run test through another terminal window?

Comment: @RavishaHesh unfortunately it outputs the same message in the new window that I run the test in

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with this Behat package.  But in laravel phpunit there is a variable to set base url,  and that also not working with absolute path of localhost(http://localhost/Blog/public).  So it might with a virtual host

Comment: what is the value of `base_url` under `Behat\MinkExtension` in behat.yml? Better yet, please give us your behat.yml file.

Comment: @MadDog I have edited the post to include behat.yml and my directory structure ... looks like the base_url is http://localhost:8888

Comment: Create a step that displays the contents of the page after you visit it (`$this->getSession()->getPage()->getContent()`). This way you will know exactly what you get.

Comment: Before the step `Then I should see "Laravel 5"` put another step `Then print last response` that will give you the current page

Comment: @IgorLantushenko great tip and here's what I uncovered: the "then print last response returns the view/html of the page rendered, with key info being <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" /> and <h1>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1>. Any idea what went wrong here? When I go to the server my page loads just fine and I see text "Laravel 5".

Comment: @IgorLantushenko btw, I changed "base_url: http://localhost:8888" to "base_url: http://localhost:8000" and now use "php artisan serve" to start up the server. I visit the URL http://localhost:8000 and see the text "Laravel 5"

Comment: @Laura_E I expected that something might be wrong with the server config, but what exactly is hard to say, try to search in the sever logs what exactly went wrong there.

Comment: @IgorLantushenko I'm sorry but my googling isn't helping. What are these server logs and how exactly do I look at them? I use mac terminal (el capitan)

Comment: @Laura_E unfortunately I'm not familiar with Laravel env, but google gives me some links to the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors)

Comment: @IgorLantushenko in case you are curious, I posted the solution below. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Laura_E you are welcome, nice job !:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally! I found via my server logs (storage/logs/laravel.log) that the page rendered contained the text "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." (obviously the wrong page). The error was "development.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.'"
There are about 50 questions and answers on StackOverflow for this, and **none** of them worked. After researching for days, finally I found my solution. It may be a combination of previous changes I had made, or the success could entirely be due to this command. In any case, try:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Phew!

Comment: Oohhhhhh my God, i can not thank you enough bro. i have helped. i began to hate behat for no reason. Once again Thanks a million you are the hero

Comment: i had the same problem , and it's fixed now thank's to you :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding APP_KEY at env.behat file